# CSS Checking a field has no value

Tags: css, null

What's the opposite of ?has_content in CSS when checking whether a field has a value or not?

I'm trying to do an if-else logic and I have two fields, FieldA and FieldB. If FieldA has content, display FieldA, else dispaly FieldB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:empty`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/) for this, but this can only work in CSS if `FieldA` comes right before `FieldB` (or a couple of other relationships, but this is the easiest one to understand).

```
.FieldA + .FieldB {
    display: none;
}
.FieldA:empty + .FieldB {
    display: block;
}
```

Since this is application logic, and it depends on a specific relationship between these elements, it's probably better to do this in your application code instead (don't print `FieldB` at all if it is not meant to be shown).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help jnylen. I instead used the <#if> <#else> clause as it is simpler to understand and maintain.